# jQuery UI WYSIWYG?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, editor, wysiwyg

I now use [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/), but I cannot style it like the rest of the page. So is there a jQuery UI WYSIWYG text editor? Or is there a way to style CLEditor with jQuery UI widget elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a RTE for this very reason. I wanted an editor that was light weight and had was 100% ui based with themeroller support. My editor uses themeroller for the design and uses regular html to create the button icons that dont exist (yet) in themeroller.

You will find the other editors linked here do not use the themeroller icons and thus are not really 100% jquery ui.

You can see my editor here: https://github.com/gcphost/jUIRTE

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully.

Comment: thanks. most my answers are not self promotion and in this (and another related topic) I did post a link to the plugin I have written because it answers the OP's exact question 'So is there a jQuery UI WYSIWYG text editor?' - there really isnt any themeroller (ui) editors so I felt the link is useful

Answer (score 3):

The CLEditor UI can be styled using the jquery.cleditor.css file. The editor's internal document can also be styled using the docCSSFile and bodyStyle optional parameter properties.

Comment: that's right, but jQuery UI uses classes to style elements, so I had to give some elements specific classes, which is not (really) possible. It would be better if there was a built-in jQuery UI WYSIWYG editor...

Answer (score 2):

I like [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) more than [elrte.org](http://elrte.org/), so I had to edit the code. Not the best solution, but the best-looking...

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly light-weight but [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) has an interface to Jquery that can be enabled by using an adaptor js file. I am using it in my current project and no pain in the basic mode.

Comment: It has an interface to jQuery, but cannot be styled like a jQuery UI widget. Or are there more skins that add jQuery UI classes (like "ui-state-default" or "ui-widget-header")?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in love with **[jQte](http://jqueryte.com/)** just 19Kb

```
$(element).jqte(); // ;)
```